# cocoa: how do I draw camera frames on to the screen

Tags: cocoa, camera, avfoundation

What I am trying to do is to display camera feeds within a NSview using AVfoundation. I know this can be easily achieved by using the "AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer". However, the long term plan is to do some frame processing for tracking hand gestures, thus I prefer to draw the frames manually. The way I did was to use the "AVCaptureVideoDataOutput" and implement the "(void)captureOutput: didOutputSampleBuffer: fromConnection:" delegate function.

Below is my implementation of the delegate function. Within the delegate function I create an CGImage from the sample buffer and render it onto an CALayer. However this does NOT work as I do not see any video frames rendered on screen. The CALayer (mDrawlayer) was created in function "awakeFromNib" and attached to a custom view in the story board. I verify the CALayer creation by setting the background colour to orange and it works.

```
- (void)captureOutput:(AVCaptureOutput *)captureOutput didOutputSampleBuffer:   (CMSampleBufferRef)sampleBuffer fromConnection:(AVCaptureConnection *)connection
{
    CVImageBufferRef pixelBuffer = CMSampleBufferGetImageBuffer(sampleBuffer);

    CVPixelBufferLockBaseAddress(pixelBuffer, 0);

    uint8_t *baseAddress = (uint8_t *)CVPixelBufferGetBaseAddress(pixelBuffer);
    size_t bytesPerRow = CVPixelBufferGetBytesPerRow(pixelBuffer);
    size_t width = CVPixelBufferGetWidth(pixelBuffer);
    size_t height = CVPixelBufferGetHeight(pixelBuffer);
    CGColorSpaceRef colorSpace = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB();
    CGContextRef newContext =
    CGBitmapContextCreate(baseAddress,width,height, 8, bytesPerRow,
                      colorSpace, kCGBitmapByteOrder32Little |
                      kCGImageAlphaPremultipliedFirst);

    CGImageRef imgRef = CGBitmapContextCreateImage(newContext);

    mDrawLayer.contents = (id) CFBridgingRelease(imgRef);
    [mDrawLayer display];

    CVPixelBufferUnlockBaseAddress(pixelBuffer, 0);
}
```

Obviously I am not doing something correctly, so how should I render the camera frames one by one onto the CALayer?
Also, I would like to know If my approach is correct. What is standard way of doing this?

Your help will be greatly appreciated. Thanks:)